# Edit Devise Controller - Add Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller, rubygems

I want to add an object (@attachment) to the new and edit actions in the controller for devise. Unfortunately I don't know how and where to do this. :|

Comment: You must improve your question and give us more details about what you desire. You can start saying which controller and what you expect after doing this.

Comment: After generationg devise there is no controller under app/controllers. That's why I don't know where to set the @attachment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the registrations controller with the same approach shown in the docs:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

And you could instantiate the object using a private method and before_filter, like so:

```
#in controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :init_attachment, only: [:new, :edit]

  private
  def init_attachment
    @attachment #= ...
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!